# Why does it ask for user input 2 times in a row everytime?

Tags: java, user-input

I want the user to insert how many sticks they want to take off from the table (from 1 to 3 sticks) and then I want the program to print out the number of sticks that are left on the table after the move.

I got this far, but I just can't understand why it asks me to put the user input twice in a row before printing the result (and the second user input is the one that counts).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class GameOfSticks {
    public static int sticks = 10;
    public static int sticksToTake;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("The number of sticks on the table is " + sticks + ".");
        System.out.print("Insert how many sticks you want to take: ");
        makeHumanMove(sticksToTake);
        System.out.println(getNumberOfSticksOnBoard());

    }

    public static int getNumberOfSticksOnBoard() {
        sticks = sticks - makeHumanMove(sticksToTake);
        return sticks;
    }

    public static int makeHumanMove(int sticksToTake) {
        Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            int enteredNumber;
                try {
                    enteredNumber = userInputScanner.nextInt();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.print("Not a number, enter a number from 1 to 3: ");
                    userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                    continue;
                }
            if (enteredNumber < 1 || enteredNumber > 3) {
                System.out.print("Incorrect number, enter a number from 1 to 3: ");
                continue;
            } else {
                sticksToTake = enteredNumber;
                return(sticksToTake);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the method `makeHumanMove` twice. Once in the **Main** method and then again in the `getNumberOfSticksOnBoard` method. If you remove `makeHumanMove(sticksToTake);` in the **Main** method then it works fine, as it just calls it once in the `getNumberOfSticksOnBoard` method.

Answer (score 0):

It works this way because you are calling makeHumanMove method twice. First time in main, second time in getNumberOfSticksOnBoard.

Comment: THANK YOU! I can't believe I couldn't realize this.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're calling makeHumanMove method twice.
First one

```
 makeHumanMove(sticksToTake);
```

and second one inside the getNumberOfSticksOnBoard method;

```
 System.out.println(getNumberOfSticksOnBoard());
```

You can try like this(Also you can modify this, I only try toput input for once. );

```
public class GameOfSticks {
    public static int sticks = 10;
    public static int sticksToTake;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("The number of sticks on the table is " + sticks + ".");
        System.out.print("Insert how many sticks you want to take: ");
        Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int enteredNumber;
        while (true) {

            try {
                enteredNumber = userInputScanner.nextInt();
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.print("Not a number, enter a number from 1 to 3: ");
                userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                continue;
            }
            makeHumanMove(enteredNumber);
            System.out.println(getNumberOfSticksOnBoard());
        }



    }

    public static int getNumberOfSticksOnBoard() {
        sticks = sticks - makeHumanMove(sticksToTake);
        return sticks;
    }

    public static int makeHumanMove(int enteredNumber) {

        if (enteredNumber < 1 || enteredNumber > 3) {
            System.out.print("Incorrect number, enter a number from 1 to 3: ");
        } else {
            sticksToTake = enteredNumber;
            return (sticksToTake);
        }
        return sticksToTake;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the line

```
makeHumanMove(sticksToTake);
```

in your main-method.
On the next line

```
 System.out.println(getNumberOfSticksOnBoard());
```

inside the method

```
getNumberOfSticksOnBoard()
```

you call

```
makeHumanMove(sticksToTake)
```

again. Thats the reason you get to do an input twice in a row. The result is wrong this way as well.